# LEFT ONLY Join in Pig (A - B)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I have two data sets

**File1**

```
11,A,2013
12,B,2014
13,C,2015
```

**File2**

```
11,A,2016,Y
15,D,2017,Y
13,C,2016,N
10,K,2017,N
```

I want to do a Left Only join based on first column on these data sets.
Here is my Pig script.

```
A_C01 = LOAD '/user/uszanr8/pigtest/file3' using PigStorage(',') ; 
B_C08 = LOAD '/user/uszanr8/pigtest/file1'  using PigStorage(','); 
C_C01_FILT = FILTER A_C01 BY $3 == 'Y';
E_JOINED_BY_CLM_NBR = JOIN C_C01_FILT BY $0 , B_C08 BY  $0 ;
DUMP E_JOINED_BY_CLM_NBR;
```

My actual data has far more records and columns.

How can I get the records from left data set that has no matches with right data set that is filtered in Pig without using cogroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = LOAD '/user/uszanr8/pigtest/file1' using PigStorage(',')  AS(l1:int,l2:chararray,l3:int); 
B = LOAD '/user/uszanr8/pigtest/file2'  using PigStorage(',') AS(r1:int,r2:chararray,r3:int,r4:chararray); 
C = FILTER B BY r4 == 'Y';
D = JOIN A BY l1  LEFT OUTER, B BY r1 ;
E = FILTER D BY r1 is NULL;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE l1,l2,l3;
DUMP F;
```

For the above code the below is output

```
12,B,2014
13,C,2015
```

If you need all records from A(left side relation) then simply remove the E relation;

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks Surender , this really helps .The above will give only one row, to get the desired answer need to change the join like                                                                                                                  D = JOIN A BY l1  LEFT OUTER, C BY r1 ;